Integrated Radeon GPU causing black screen on a hybrid GPU laptop
Laptop specifications:
  • Model: Lenovo IdeaPad gaming laptop
  • Processor: AMD Ryzen 5
  • Integrated GPU: Radeon graphics
  • Dedicated GPU: Nvidia GTX 1650
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64 desktop  ( 6.8.0-39-generic kernel )
I am experiencing persistent black screen issues related to the integrated Radeon GPU on my Lenovo IdeaPad gaming laptop. This problem occurs during the installation of any Linux distribution and continues after installing both Nvidia and AMD drivers.
Steps taken:

During installation, I used the nomodeset parameter, which allowed me to boot successfully, however after installing the Nvidia and AMD drivers the black screen issue reoccurs.

I disabled the integrated Radeon GPU, which resulted in the display output only coming from the external monitor. The laptop's internal display stopped working.

I have tried several distributions, including Ubuntu, Fedora, Kubuntu, Pop!_OS, and Arch Linux, but the issue persists across all of them.

Blacklisted AMD-related drivers. I tried different versions of Nvidia drivers. Used open source Xorg drivers.

I updated the BIOS firmware in hopes of resolving the display issue, but it did not help.


The laptop's internal display remains nonfunctional, while the external display works fine. The issue seems to be rooted in the integrated Radeon GPU. I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue so that both the internal and external displays function correctly without black screen problems.

Maybe kernel issue. Try switch kernel or in Grub, replace this:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

by
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"

then sudo update-grub
